# How do I install modules into the maven repository using Netbeans embedded Maven?

Tags: maven-2, netbeans

I have the Maven plugin for NetBeans and it successfully set up a local repository for me. Now I need to add a 3rd party library (specifically Oracle JDBC driver) to my repository. The build fails with instructions on how to install a third party module but it doesn't look like I can run that command with the NetBeans Maven plugin. Is this possible, or do I need to just get the external version of Maven?

Comment: You added the module as dependency in your Maven project (in the pom.xml) and it won't install it automatically?

Comment: Yeah, my understanding is that you have to get the Oracle module directly from Oracle and install it in your maven repository because the main maven repository can't redistribute it because of license issuse maybe? I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you could do (at least in NetBeans 6.5) is following:

- add dependency to the library in your pom
- go to Projects->your project->Libraries (you should see the library with exclamation mark)
- right click on the library, choose 'Manually install artifact'
- select the jar from local drive, 'Install locally' and you are done!

Comment: For netbeans 8.0.2 I had to go to Projects -> my project then expand Dependencies and right click the library -> Manually install artifact

Answer (score 4):

I ended up downloading Maven here:
http://maven.apache.org/download.html
and using the standalone Maven binaries to install the jar into my Maven repository. If anyone has any thoughts on the question, I am still interested in knowing the answer.