# How to install jars in maven repository which is eclipse embedded?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

My objective is to install a jar file in a Maven repository. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164043/maven-how-to-include-jars-which-are-not-available-in-reps-into-a-j2ee-project/1164552#1164552) explains how to do an install with MVN.

But but since I have Maven embedded in Eclipse, I don't know where to run the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=C:\lib\rest\WadlGenerator.jar \
                          -DgroupId=foo.in.shop.rest.wadl \
                          -DartifactId=WadlGenerator \
                          -Dversion=1.0 \
                          -Dpackaging=jar \
                          -DlocalRepositoryPath=C:\maven\repositories\internal
```

In short: How can I identify the Maven installation directory for Eclipse-embedded Maven?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From eclipse you can do:

Run -> Run Configurations -> Maven Build (double click)

Your goal is install:install-file

And also you should fill parameters' keys and values

P. S. But I think that it is more better to have external maven installation in system

Comment: As you told I did everything. But I'm getting this error. http://pastebin.com/NGYXKDU2

Comment: I 'm passin the below parameters -Dfile               
-DgroupId            
-DartifactId         
-Dversion            
-Dpackaging          
-DlocalRepositoryPath

Comment: Its worth noting you should add parameter names without the '-D', and you only need 'file', 'groupId', 'artifactId', 'version' and 'packaging'.

Comment: This answer is now unnecessary, as the answer below it provides a much simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can simply do:
1. Run 
2. Maven Build.. 
3. Copy the whole command in Goals i.e.

```
install:install-file  -Dfile=C:\lib\rest\WadlGenerator.jar \
                          -DgroupId=foo.in.shop.rest.wadl \
                          -DartifactId=WadlGenerator \
                          -Dversion=1.0 \
                          -Dpackaging=jar \
                          -DlocalRepositoryPath=C:\maven\repositories\internal
```

4. Run

This is much easier than filling keys and values :D

Answer (score 3):

If you have M2Eclipse installed, and you have a Maven pom building the jar, use

> Run -> Run As... -> Maven Install

from the Eclipse menu to do the equivalient of 
`mvn install`

Answer (score 1):

The default location for the maven repository would be ~/.m2/repository.

Unless you changed this in the preferences of your eclipse plugin, then you should go with that. Replace the ~/ with whatever is appropriate for your home dir on your OS.

Edit: Updating based on the comments:
There's an online book available for the m2eclipse plugin, and it would appear that you can run goals from the m2eclipse plugin - see the section here: [m2eclipse Goals](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/preferences.html#fig-preferences-goal-lifecycle)

I presume there is a wizard of some sort when you click on the goal - I don't have m2eclipse installed here.

Edit2: actually looking at the other answer, this has been answered already :)

Comment: But What I need is installation directory which is different from the rep dir.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. I would still install a version of maven on your local system, for these exceptional cases. Eclipse plug-ins are all well and good until you need to do something like this. Some of the plug-ins also allow you to use the external maven install, so that would prevent issues with different versions.

Comment: Yes I can install another maven installation. But I need to do things with Default Eclipse maven. Any luck?

Comment: Which plugin are you using? m2eclipse or mavenide?

Comment: Glad to see your reply. It's m2eclipse