# How to add dependency to jfugue using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jfugue

I'm working on a project on Eclipse IDE that requires jfugue. How do I add this dependency to my project, using Maven?

I tried to:

1. Right click to the project name->Maven->Add Dependency;
2. I added a dependency from pom.xml form:

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfugue</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <type>java-source</type>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. I added the repository:

   ```
   <repository>
    <id>jfugue-repo</id>
    <url>http://jfugue.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jfugue/</url>
   </repository>
   ```
4. It search files with a broken link but I can't see it because it not appear for more than one second in the Progress View.

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE 1**
jfugue pom.xml is [this](http://jfugue.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jfugue/pom.xml).
Mine pom.xml is [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=i5HaV3GG).

Comment: I don't think the url given is a maven repository

Comment: Sorry for issue. Now the link points to the main project. There is a pom.xml file and I think that jfugue is a project based on maven.

Comment: Could you post the pom.xml from that url or just repository?

Comment: I added mine and jfugue pom.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the pom.xml doesn't have remote repositories. Use the following [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to figure out how to install jar into the local repository. You have also remove `<repository` tag from your project's pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks Roman for you answer. How can I do the same thing with m2e?

Comment: After you have installed the jar to the local repository you can add dependency using m2e editor of pom.xml or by action wizard.

Comment: Yes but I don't use maven in command line. I have only m2e plugin for Eclipse. Is there a way to install the jar in the local repository?

Comment: Now the problem is solved. I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4324057/1992780) to create a custom command line run to import the jar in the local repository and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/) to include the jar in my project.

Comment: @DavidePastore I like that you solved the problem. Note, it seems you like to play with eclipse, but be aware that eclipse itself if a good tool but not all the problems you could solve with it. If you are working with maven first thing you should do is install maven and configure it to run from the command line, it's my suggestions and always read original docs from the maven site. However, it regards to all Apache projects. Happy that helped you.