# Use Maven embedded in Eclipse to install dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to add log4j as a Maven Dependency.  So I added it to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I have a warning message that I am missing 6 artifacts (jars that log4j depends on).  As described on the following site [Maven Repository - log4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.15).

My goal is to get Maven to install the 6 dependencies for me.  I have Eclipse Kepler with embedded Maven, so I cannot run "mvn install".  I see from this stackoverflow answer [Run Maven Install in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323981/how-to-install-jars-in-maven-repository-which-is-eclipse-embedded) that I can right click on the project and Run As > Maven Install.  But I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ############# 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.522s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 27 12:13:11 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project #############: Could not resolve dependencies for project #############:#############:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1, com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No connector available to access repository java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Please let me know if I am on the right path and how best to proceed to get the log4j dependencies.  Thank you in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**
After checking Preferences > Maven > User Settings, I discovered that the settings.xml file that is being referenced does not exist.  I clicked "Update Settings" and I get the following error:

```
ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No connector available to access repository java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

**UPDATE 2**
It looks like my issue is a result of Maven 3 (which comes with Kepler) is trying to access a Maven 2 repository and having compatibility issues.  I have yet to figure out how to redirect to an appropriate repository.

Comment: For the sake of sanity and IDE independence, I strongly recommend you to install Maven in your machine and run the build by it, instead of using the embedded one.

Comment: For sanity's sake, I think I may be done experimenting with Maven.

Comment: Manen is a powerful tool, but as uncle Ben said: "With great power comes great responsibility". You can't use it partially, you have to understand it and accept its issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the version from 1.2.15 to 1.2.17 and it worked (1.2.16 works as well).  I do not see any of the dependencies listed "[here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17)" listed in the Resolved Dependencies frame like I did with 1.2.15.  I do not have a full understanding of why this worked, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on your project then Maven > Update Snapshots. (Make sure u check the "Force update on snapshots" checkbox. This should work.

Comment: I have the option Maven > Update Project.  I ran that, but it did not help.  It did not print a log to the console...

Comment: When you do Maven > Update Snapshots, it will update the repository from C:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository folder in Windows in mac  ~/.m2 so the local repository is updated and you dont see anything updated in the console.