# How to add a jar file when using mvn command to compile a project

Tags: maven

I need to add a jar file to compile my project using maven command, but this jar file is not from another  maven depository,it's just a jar file. I don't know how to and this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go thru this..

[Maven: How to include jars, which are not available in reps into a J2EE project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164043/maven-how-to-include-jars-which-are-not-available-in-reps-into-a-j2ee-project)

Make sure you have -Dpackaging=jar

More info..

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/