# How create a dependency to others local projects

Tags: android, maven

I have an Android project. This project have another two other projects of my company added. 
To do that, in Android, I made right click on the project, then selected properties, then android, then libraries, then click add button and selected the two local folders where the projects are placed.

After do that, when I compile my project, android compile the other two projects and "automatically" are added to my project.

Now, I need to do the same, but using Maven. How can i do?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the projects are Maven projects then you can easily create a multi module project. Check [this guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) for details. The TL;DR would be to add a parent pom which would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Multi Module Parent Example</name>

    <modules>
        <module>android-app</module>
        <module>other-project1</module>
        <module>other-project2</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then you have a directory structure like this:

```
my-projects/
| pom.xml <-- The above pom
| android-app/
+-+ pom.xml
| \ ...
| other-project1/
+-+ pom.xml
| \ ...
| other-project2/
+-+ pom.xml
  \ ...
```

**EDIT:** If you want to include jars from non-Maven projects into your build automatically, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305679/maven-and-eclipse-a-reliable-way-to-add-non-maven-or-external-jars-to-a-project) and its accepted answer. The TL;DR here is to add something like this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>own-project1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>../own-project1/target/own-project1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>own-project2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>../own-project3/target/own-project3.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But my other projects aren't maven projects and I can't convert them.

Comment: OK, how and where do you want the projects to be imported then? When you build the application and as jars?

Comment: Yes, my idea is: when maven generate my apk, have to compile the other projects and use it.

Comment: thanks, I will try your answer. Sadly right now my Project Manager change my tasks, so I still can't try

Answer (score 0):

Either you dependent projects are *maven* projects, so there will be no additional staff to do and here where *maven* makes things easier and you can simply declare a dependency to other projects:

```
<project>
  <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</project>
```

Or when the dependent modules are non mavenized projects, you can install the archives (jars) to your local repository so they can be later used as maven dependencies:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=PATH_TO_JAR_FILE.jar -DgroupId=some.group.id -DartifactId=some-artifact-id -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then the upside pom.xml file snapshot remain legal.