# Access dependencies of project on build path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

So I have a large Java project, which I'll call ProjectA. I have another project, ProjectB, which is a Maven project, and includes ProjectA as a dependency (by compiling ProjectA to a jar file). I also have many other Maven projects: ProjectC1, ProjectC2, etc. Each of these include ProjectB as a Maven dependency.

ProjectB contains code meant to be common/accessible to all of the ProjectC projects, as well as act as an interface to access some functionality from ProjectA. The problem is: in order to do this, I either have to write a method/class in ProjectB that explicitly calls/extends the method/class from ProjectA that I want to call, or I have to explicitly include ProjectA itself as a dependency in the ProjectCx project (which is undesirable due to the size of ProjectA).

Is there a way to access the members of ProjectA indirectly from ProjectC via ProjectB somehow?

Comment: Are they all maven projects? Have you [read](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) about the `transitive dependencies` and `dependency scopes`? Still think they don't fit your needs?

Comment: B and C are Maven projects, but A isn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you defined B as a dependency in the pom.xml of project C.
and A is a dependency in B.
than in C you have access to A.
thats what you call transitive dependencies in maven.
meaning C automatically, even without writing project A in the c pom.xml, you get project A in your classpath.
thats how maven works by default.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer here: [Maven and eclipse: a reliable way to add non-Maven or external jars to a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305679/maven-and-eclipse-a-reliable-way-to-add-non-maven-or-external-jars-to-a-project)

I added the Project A jar as a system dependency to Project B, and it picked up the transitive dependency in Project C.