# How do I convert a exist Java project to maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I've installed m2eclipse, and using the embedded Maven3.

Now I want to add dependencies to my project(there are existing jars), but the search result is always 0, how do I deal with this ?

I don't want to download all jars for now, just want to create the dependencies now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"spring" and "spring" are not valid specifiers for the Spring libraries.

Here is a link to a helpful article about artifact names for Spring:

http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

You should be using names like:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert a project to eclipse maven project, you can open terminal and run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

or convert to idea maven project:

```
mvn idea:idea
```

Comment: That works if you already have pom.xml with all dependencies. Does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `spring-context` instead of `spring`. If you are not sure about the name of the artifact you are looking for you can use wildcards, eg `*spring*.`

Comment: I tried to use *spring*, but it doesn't work. It seems maven doesn't search remote server, and I don't have these jars in local rep.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog in your question is a bit confusing. It's actually two dialogs and should be using tabs. In the upper part, you can manually add a dependency if you happen to know all the details.

In the lower part, you can search for dependencies. The search will only work if you leave the fields at the top empty.

Comment: If I leave the top empty, it shows an error `Artifact Id cannot be empy`, and doesn't take the search action.

Comment: Which version of m2e?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see, you want to use along with the maven dependencies existing in the project, right?

Assuming your project structure already in structured maven, you can follow this tip below, but beware, i think maybe you can have some sort of conflict between dependencies..

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320920/1133742
- http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/06/how-add-external-libraries-maven/

Use the website below to browse dependencies:

- http://mvnrepository.com/