# How to add my own jar file in maven project

Tags: java, maven

How to add my own jar file in maven project. When I try to add by using build path it's not recognizing classes in my jar file.

is there any specific way of doing it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use system scope and provide path OR you can install your custom jar to your local maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/your.jar -DgroupId=com.your.group.id 
-DartifactId=your-custom-artifact-id -Dversion=some-version -Dpackaging=jar
```

and/or maven repository which is shared across developers

Answer (score 2):

This link http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html shows how to use maven import to add your own jars to your maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```