# Configuring to Maven Project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was using eclipse for building my project. Now I am configuring the project to Maven project. All the libs were manually downloaded to lib folder. If I do a Maven build, Maven is unable to map those libs. There are lots of libs, I don't want to manually place them in pom.xml. What is the best way out?

I have read few answers, first declare local repo and then add the respective dependencies. But again I don't want to add all the dependencies manually.

[Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)

Comment: As far as I know, you need all of your dependencies in the pom.xml so you'll need to add them there. Maybe you can write a script that reads all the jar filenames and have it output the XML you need to add to your pom.xml ?

Comment: I got this script from one of the answers: https://github.com/nikita-volkov/install-to-project-repo
But its not able to parse all the libs.

Comment: Either modify it so it works for you or create your own script that outputs the required XML. :)

Comment: Okay u mean pom.xml MUST have dependencies declared?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 0):

**1.) Install locally**

There are two scopes which are interesting for you. If you declare a scope "runtime" (which is the default scope) and have a local repository configured, maven will try to download the file from your local repository.

**2.) System dependency**

If you just don't want maven to manage dependencies, you can (although shan't) use the system scope like this:

```
<dependency>
    ...
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/path/to/dependency.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The downsides are:

- the system scope is deprecated and might not work in future versions of maven.
- you need to check in a jar file, [which is not a good idea](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/192115).
- it may not be portable (e.g. architecture dependent libraries).