# Consume custom jar in spring MVC project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I need to create a website using Spring MVC so I'm using STS for this purpose. I'm also using maven as a build tool.

I'm new to java so I'm having a hard time figuring where to keep thing or what directory structure to follow. STS helped me create a Starter Spring project which looks like the following

[image: Project Structure]

I have a custom jar file xyz.jar that I need to consume as a service in this website.

Can some please guide me where this file should be kept and how to include it in the build output ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below maven command  with corresponding parameters it will create a folder inside `.m2` folder and add jar there

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\JarLocation\xyz.jar -DgroupId=<Add Group Id for your Jar> -DartifactId=<Add Artifact ID> -Dversion=<Add Version>  -Dpackaging=jar
```

then in your `pom.xml` make a entry for this `dependency`

For example you can check how i achieve it.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\hariom\JavaEncryptPassword-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.oss.mdf -DartifactId=java.encrypt.password -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and in my `pom.xml` file i added this entry

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oss.mdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>java.encrypt.password</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did see this answer in a few posts I searched but I just didn't understand what group id or artifact id I should be giving to a jar that already has its own namespace and is already an artifact 'xyz.jar' (If i'm thinking correctly)

Comment: Just a quick question, does the groupid, articfactid and version have to be exactly the same as what is in the jar or am I telling maven how to store it by defining these attributes?

Comment: No it not mandatory see in my case also jar file name is like this `JavaEncryptPassword-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`   but my artifactid,version i made which i like