# Maven need some files from another project available for compile

Tags: java, maven

I have two different projects using maven 3.2.5/3.0.5 (3.2.5 locally, 3.0.5 on build server). The first creates jar files needed to compile the second. Both projects will run in an environment and so my second project doesn't need to have the most current version, it just needs to them to compile against.

This seems like I'm making it way harder than it needs to be. I was using system and specifying a system path, but evidently maven feels like that is substandard structure and it quit working.

We tried using our organization's artifactory instance, but that was a disaster. Probably something in their implementation of it.

I tried creating a repository for the project, and using a file URL, but it appears when you do this, that it ignores the other repository and uses that directory exclusively.

So seriously, I just need to add a couple of jar files to the path. Isn't there a way to do this in maven?

Comment: What the hell is wrong with this question, downvoter?

Comment: What is the maven version you are using?

Comment: Also, I think this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project

Comment: @JorgeCampos Edited to answer your question.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The problem with that approach is that it requires me to have access to our build server, which I don't. :(

Comment: From that link, I was talking about the IN-PROJECT repository solution, the one with most upvotes. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: @JorgeCampos No, that was the one I tried with the file URL. It replaces the default repository.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. But I have to say that you really should try to implement a repository management system and use the snapshots features.

Comment: The correct solution to your problem is to have a repository manager and add those jar to it. "but that was a disaster" is not really descriptive: what went wrong?