# adobe AEM com.adobe.granite.api maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, aem

I am using AEM 6.1 with Maven to manage dependencies. I can see the bundle com.adobe.granite.poi version 2.0.0 being shipped along with the AEM instance. But I cant seem to find a maven dependency for the library in both Adobe public repository as well as Maven central repository.

I have checked the uber-jar dependency uber-jar-6.1.0-obfuscated-apis and could not locate it there as well.

I can find version 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 of com.adobe.granite.poi in the Adobe public nexus. I would prefer to avoid using a older version if possible. How would you manage this problem.

Comment: did you check this question/answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find granite poi 2.0.0 here - http://nexus.citytech.ctmsp.com/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/com.adobe.granite.poi/2.0.0/

BTW, I have had this experience with a couple of apis whose newer version are not available on adobe's maven repository, but they are shipped with AEM. what my understanding is that if its not available on adobe-public, its not (or not any longer) a public api and you are not supposed to use it. you may want to find an alternative.

Comment: That makes sense. I would have expected Adobe to document this clearly though. I will go for the apache poi from maven central in this case I guess.