# How to add non-maven jars to classpath?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have to add some non-maven jars into a Spring boot project (MVC). Those jars are not built by maven or gradle or ..., and the don't have a `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` or ...

The jars are provided by a company, and they have no plan to host those jars on any maven repositories even their own (actually they don't have a private maven repo).

My project structure is like

```
my-app/
  |-lib
  |  |-some.jar
  |  |-other.jar
  |
  |-src/
     |-main/
     |   |-java/
     |   |-resources/
     |
     |-test/
         |-java/
```

I added a folder `lib/` to the project root, and put those non-maven jars in it. The problem is how can I configure `pom.xml` to include those jars in classpath? Or can I put those jars in some other folder to avoid twisting maven configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them)

Comment: I've read that post, but can I add jars to classpath without installing those jars to my local maven repo?

Comment: check `<scope>system</scope>` for dependency. You have to be very careful, as jar file created this way is not portable by default

Comment: I added `<scope>system</scope>`, but I didn't put those jars into java home because they depends on GSON. I tried `<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/some.jar</systemPath>` but failed in building.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this :

For example i want to add ojdbc-7.jar on my repository, i go to my repository 
\USERFolder\Laptop_Login.m2\repository\ojdbc\ojdbc\7
and i create manually the path ojdbc\ojdbc\7\ and in the path 7 i put my File Jar.

dependency
groupId ojdbc groupId
artifactId ojdbc artifactId
version 7 version 
dependency

between the tag's value of artifactId and the tag's value of version add a mince like this (ojdbc-7).

i think it's the better way to do.

Comment: "i think it's the better way to do.", well, I wouldn't say so, mvn install:install-file would do exactly the same, but not manually, less error-prone, more standard, but still less portable build