# How to add Orchid (Tor Java Lib) to my project?

Tags: java, maven, tor

I need help with adding Orchid to java project. I'm using maven to add dependencies but I don't know how to add Orchid repository to my project.
[Here is more info about orchid](https://subgraph.com/orchid/index.en.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is the same library (since site you indicated informs only version 1.0), but there is another Orchid (Tor client) available in maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
    <artifactId>orchid</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! This repository has Orchid Library that I need. Version doesn't meter to me. :)