# package com.sun.deploy.net.proxy does not exist

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I'm trying to connect to an URL through a proxy script. 
So I'm using the following code :

```
    try {
        URL myURL = new URL("https://aaa.com");
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "policy.all");
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
        BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();
        b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
        b.setAutoConfigURL("http://bbb.com/wpad.dat");
        SunAutoProxyHandler handler = new SunAutoProxyHandler();
        try {
            handler.init(b);
            ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(myURL);
            for (ProxyInfo p : ps) {
                System.out.println(p.toString());
            }
        } catch (ProxyConfigException e) {
            log.error("error=> ProxyConfigException ", e);
        } catch (ProxyUnavailableException e) {
            log.error("error=> ProxyUnavailableException ", e);
        }

        URLConnection c = myURL.openConnection();
        c.connect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("error=> MalformedURLException ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("error=> IOException ", e);
    }
```

I can run the code.
But when I try to build it with Maven I got an error :

> package com.sun.deploy.net.proxy does not exist
>
> [ERROR]
>   /.../App.java:[135,17]
>   cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol:   class BrowserProxyInfo

I haven't find any maven dependencies about `com.sun.deploy.net.proxy` to add in the pom.

Here are my java infos :

> java version "1.8.0_131"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

This is my maven build :

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.zzz</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-full</finalName>
      <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I haven't found any other way to connect to an URL through a proxy script.
Do you have any idea of this problem ? Or another way to connect ?

Comment: _"I can run the code."_ -- So what is the difference between when YOU run it vs when Maven runs it.  Please explain in detail, without that the question is really off-topic.  Clearly you have forgotten to include a dependency in your `pom.xml`

Comment: the deploy.jar is not on your classpath. Can you post the folder structure of the generated jar-with-dependencies jar? You can try adding <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> in your <manifest> attribure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing deploy.jar in classpath, that you need to download and setup maven dependency.

First download deploy.jar: https://github.com/barchart/barchart-oracle-study/blob/master/oracle-jdk-7.21-deploy/deploy.jar

Add the downloaded jar in maven dependency(pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.user.deploy</groupId>
  <artifactId>deploy-jar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath><jar path></systemPath>
</dependency>
```

You can even install this jar in maven local repository:

read: [Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)