# Maven dependencies for notes.jar java?

Tags: java, maven

What will be maven dependency for notes.jar java? I am using lotus notes and I have Notes.jar with me.
I have already tried searching for dependency on MVN repository, on our local repository.

Comment: You won't find that JAR in any Maven central repo, since Notes is a licensed IBM product.  If you are allowed by license to put it in a repo you'll have to run mvn install to put it where you wish.

Comment: Does it have a pom.xml? you can see the groupId, artifactId and version there

Comment: [Very similar, you might want to read this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the context that you are talking about the `Notes.jar` file that is distributed as part of Lotus Notes.

As @Duffymo points out, you will not find this in the Maven central repositories<sup>1</sup>.  It is proprietary software that is made available to people who have obtained the relevant software license from IBM.

One solution is to use `mvn install:install-file` to put a copy of the JAR (with appropriate ids) into your local repository.  There may be others; see

- [Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)

... but  beware of publishing the JAR file any more broadly than your Lotus Notes license agreement permits.  (Hint: read it!)

---

<sup>1 - If anyone put the `Notes.jar` file into a public repository, that would be license violation, placing them, the repository owners and anyone who downloads the file ... and their respective organizations ... at risk of being sued.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but I needed to go back to this and I wrote a blog about it on a site that is longer running.

**Adding Notes.jar (Domino) to Maven Repository**
Posted on May 26, 2019 by Slobodan Posted in XPagesBeast

To build JavaAgents, or XPages applications with better quality and less Domino dependencies. I will need to build the business logic outside Domino where it can be reused with non Domino apps.

Maven loads all dependencies into your ~.m2

Navigate to where you have Notes.jar with your terminal.

Windows

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\jvm\lib\ext>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=notes.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.domino -DartifactId=lotus
.domino -Dversion=10.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\jvm\lib\ext\notes.jar to C:\Users\home-dir\.m2\repository\com\ibm\domino\lotus.do
mino\10.0.1\lotus.domino-10.0.1.jar
[INFO] Installing c:\temp\mvninstall1256224580517013755.pom to C:\Users\home-dir\.m2\repository\com\ibm\domino\lotus.domino\10.0.1\l
otus.domino-10.0.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.679 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-25T23:15:51-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Check your home directory

```
C:\Users\home-dir\.m2\repository\com\ibm\domino\lotus.domino\10.0.1>dir
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 22DE-547E

Directory of C:\Users\home-dir\.m2\repository\com\ibm\domino\lotus.domino\10.0.1

05/25/2019 11:15 PM <DIR> .
05/25/2019 11:15 PM <DIR> ..
11/29/2018 02:06 AM 2,049,406 lotus.domino-10.0.1.jar
05/25/2019 11:15 PM 471 lotus.domino-10.0.1.pom
05/25/2019 11:15 PM 189 _remote.repositories
3 File(s) 2,050,066 bytes
2 Dir(s) 63,635,619,840 bytes free

C:\Users\home-dir\.m2\repository\com\ibm\domino\lotus.domino\10.0.1
```

Now with Maven’s Pom.xml I can do this (exclude the Notes.jar from being packaged because I’ll use the XPages runtime.):

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.domino</groupId>
      <artifactId>lotus.domino</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion> <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
         <groupId>com.ibm.domino</groupId>
         <artifactId>lotus.domino</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```