# How to add eBay JAVA SDK to the SBT or Maven project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, ebay-api

I'm trying to find out how to add eBay Java SDK for eBay REST API to the SCALA 2.13.8 SBT project. How to add eBay JAVA SDK to the SBT or Maven project?

eBay JAVA SDK page: https://developer.ebay.com/develop/ebay-sdks/java-sdk

Available versions for download are 1131 and 1113. According to Trading API Release Notes, they are outdated, the up-to-date version is 1257.

Trading API Release Notes: https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

I've looked on the mvnrepository.com, but this SDK is not represented there: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ebay?p=1

Furthermore, I can't find a source code on eBay GitHub: https://github.com/orgs/eBay/repositories?q=sdk&type=all&language=java&sort=

Comment: https://developer.ebay.com/develop/ebay-sdks/java-sdk must be REALLY old since it says Sun J2SE SDK

Comment: I wonder if https://github.com/rjdavis3/ebay-sdk is any good

Answer (score 1):

The download for that Java SDK includes the source and a pom.xml in the maven_build directory. You can use that to build the dependency and have it in your local maven repo.

From there, you can either set that build up as a maven module to get built before your code, or you can take the jar and commit it with your code and use maven to install it at build time.

Here is how you can use maven to install it from an in-project repo
[Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)