# How to access com.sun.pdfview from maven?

Tags: java, maven, pdfview

I am trying to compile iText 2.7.1 code in a maven project. This code has a dependency to `com.sun.pdfview`. I know about the [guide to coping with Sun jars](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html), but it is not in the list.

Anyone has a solution? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kenai.nbpwr</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-sun-pdfview</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5-201003191900</version>
    <type>nbm</type>
</dependency>
```

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cpdfview

Answer (score 3):

Project page including the source at [pdf-renderer](http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/)

After compiling it to jar, following explains how to include it in maven [maven include jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164043/maven-how-to-include-jars-which-are-not-available-in-reps-into-a-j2ee-project)

Comment: Yes, I found that and checked-out the code to include it in me project as a workaround. May be someone has a maven solution...