# Add jars in a maven module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I download Weasis code and run it on Eclipse using maven. 
Now I create a new class that use JMF so I want to add jmf.jar.
I follow the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164043/maven-how-to-include-jars-which-are-not-available-in-reps-into-a-j2ee-project) but I take the follow

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project weasis-base-ui: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[14,19] package javax.media does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[15,19] package javax.media does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[16,19] package javax.media does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[17,19] package javax.media does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[18,27] package javax.media.control does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[19,26] package javax.media.format does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[20,24] package javax.media.util does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[33,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Player
[ERROR] location: class org.weasis.base.ui.gui.WeasisVideo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Ioanna/git/Weasis/weasis-base/weasis-base-ui/src/main/java/org/weasis/base/ui/gui/WeasisVideo.java:[36,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Buffer
```

Do anyone know what is the problem. The class file that I used the jmf function doesn't appears errors.

Comment: Looks like you haven't added the `javax.media` package to your maven install.

Comment: But other classes used javax without problem