# TinyRadius maven repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am looking for Latest TinyRadius maven repository artifact id

Can any one tell me the dependency information for TinyRadius jar so that I can add to my pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pom from the [latest TinyRadius release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyradius/files/) (which is 1.0) contains the following information:

```
<groupId>org.tinyradius</groupId>
<artifactId>tinyradius</artifactId>
```

However it also has the following information:

```
<version>0.9.9</version>
```

So the version in the pom doesn't match the actual release which contains the pom. I also can not find this artifact in any maven repository under this groupId and artifactId, but these are the only values that they could be - based on the pom at least.

You could simply download the jar from sourceforge and then manually include it in your pom from your local drive or maven repository - see this question for details on:
[Maven: Including jar not found in public repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355548/maven-including-jar-not-found-in-public-repository)