# Maven dependency that is online and not in repository

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on a project and I need slick-util, which doesn't have really good support or anything atm. The problem is that I am using a maven system and there is no maven repository. I was wondering if I should use something like:

```
<groupId>slick</groupId>
<artifactId>slick-util</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<systemPath>http://whatever.com/slick/slick-util.jar</systempath>
<scope>system</scope>
```

I tried doing something like that, but IntelliJ Idea(my ide) says it cannot find the directory. Is there something I am doing wrong, or if this won't work, is there another method of accomplishing what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: downloading files from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url) - there are actually a couple different maven plugins for doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: Including jar not found in public repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355548/maven-including-jar-not-found-in-public-repository)

Answer (score 3):

A system dependency will not read from a URL.

Your reasonable choices are:

1. obtain and install a repo manager, such as Nexus or Artifactory.
2. mvn install:install-file to put it into your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1) Do a plain `mvn install` so Maven can find `slick-util` in your local *.m2* repository.

2) Publish the jar to a local Nexus or Artifactory repository, and identify the repository url within the `repositories` section of the pom.

3) Do an `mvn installl:install-file` so Maven can find the jar in another folder:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> 
                         -DgroupId=<myGroup> 
                         -DartifactId=<myArtifactId> 
                         -Dversion=<myVersion> 
                         -Dpackaging=<myPackaging> 
                         -DlocalRepositoryPath=<path-to-repo>
```

Here is information on the [Maven install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

1) Download slick-util.jar into your PC

2) Install it to your local repository giving it some group name and version, for example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/slick-util.jar -DgroupId=slick-util -DartifactId=slick-util -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

3) Add the dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>slick-util</groupId>
  <artifactId>slick-util</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slick Util is in Maven but in separate repository - Clojars not Central. See [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/slick-util/slick-util).

[image]

What you need is to add this into your `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>clojars</id>
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>slick-util</groupId>
        <artifactId>slick-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```