# Managing native libraries with Maven

Tags: maven-2, native

Is it possible to manage native libraries (.so) under maven?

We use some jars with dependences on external native libs, so I'm looking for some way to mavenize them.

Thanks.

Comment: This prior answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven/1020101#1020101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the "common" approach is to bundle the native libraries in platform specific JARs using classifiers (e.g. `mylib-1.2.3-solaris.jar`) on which you could depend like any other JAR with classifier:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
  <classifier>solaris</classifier>
</dependency>
```

And then, unpack them with the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and the [`unpack-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) mojo.

Also have a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962718/maven-and-the-jogl-library/1969077#1969077), the [Wrapping a Native Library with Maven](https://web.archive.org/web/20151115191414/http://www.humboldt.co.uk/wrapping-a-native-library-with-maven/) post and the section [5.5.3. Platform Classifiers](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-tips-tricks.html#profiles-sect-platform-classifier) of the *Maven: the complete reference*,

Comment: Many thanks indeed ! It helped for deploying JOGL and GlueGen native jars the proper way. :-)