# Maven and native libraries

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, java-native-interface, native

I use maven in my java project, and I don't understand how to add in native libraries. In my non-maven project I did it via CLASSPATH. I use NetBeans and maven in my current java project.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410384/managing-native-libraries-with-maven?

Comment: i don't want to do jar and unpack it, is it possible use only something like CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to add the native libraries to the class path, try to put them in `src/main/resources`.

**Update:** You can specify where [resources](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) exist in the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/native</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>native.so</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      ...
    </testResources>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

But honestly, if you decide to use Maven, you should adopt Maven's [standard layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (or you'll have to configure every plugin for your custom layout which is more a source of problems than benefits).

Comment: sorry, i'm newbie in maven, but my project have different structure. what i should to do?

Comment: @EK Either put the native libraries in the directory you defined as `<resource>` or add details to your question (like your POM and project structure) so that I can provide more guidance.

Comment: my project structure very simple.
only one folder /src/ (and test, bin, config,target, lib).
what i should change in pom, to said maven use resource folder with libs.
this is most interesting part of my pom, i think
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

THANKS!

Comment: in my classpath i have environment variable with path to libraries

Comment: @EK This is not how things work in Maven and, actually, a JNI project is really not the easiest way to start with Maven. Maybe you should stick with Ant here (especially if you don't want to follow maven's principles and conventions).

Comment: i did next
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>
                   resources
               </directory>
               <includes>
                   <include>*.so</include>
               </includes>
           </resource>
       </resources>
        <plugins>
but when i run project, it is not see libs. all libs in folder resources

Comment: maybe it is somthing like LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: @EK You'll find some answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410384/managing-native-libraries-with-maven and the various links mentioned in there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962718/maven-and-the-jogl-library/1969077#1969077, http://www.humboldt.co.uk/2009/02/wrapping-a-native-library-with-maven.html). As I said, JNI isn't an easy topic and analyzing snippets posted in a 600 chars box isn't really possible. Moreover, your problem is kinda hard to reproduce so I'm sorry but I can't help more.