# maven resolve native binaries directly

Tags: java, maven

I have a native binary (call it `abc.so`) that I'd like my Java project to resolve through Maven (so it will be part of the classpath)

The spelling of the artifact name to be exactly `abc.so`, not `abc-[baseVersion].so` which maven seems to enforce

There does not appear to be a way to do this?

If I deploy the artifact to an Artifactory instance under some arbitrary path, without a base version, can I still point maven to resolve it correctly?

Comment: Have a look at this question that seems related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448351/maven-and-native-libraries

Comment: TL;DR no.There is something called scope=system, but it has several issues and should be avoided at all  costs.Why you are trying to avoid maven naming conventions? You can still deploy to artifactory with correct version so it can be resolved

Comment: I need to circumvent the baseVersion because the .so file would otherwise not be picked up by System.loadLibrary(), and I do not control that ...