# 3D graphics library for Java that supports Maven

Tags: java, opengl, maven, java-3d

Is there any 3D graphics library for Java that supports maven and is in maven central (meaning that it can be included in a project by simply adding a maven dependency and nothing more)?

I have looked into the following, none of which can be used with maven without either creating your own artifact for it, or adding a whole bunch of extra hacks to your pom.xml

- Java3D http://java3d.java.net/
- JMonkeyEngine http://jmonkeyengine.com/
- JOGL http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/
- jPCT http://www.jpct.net/

Comment: In answer [maven and the jogl library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962718/maven-and-the-jogl-library) you can find how to use JOGL with maven..

Comment: I wonder, why do you have such a strange requirement? You can always roll out your own repository and install the required jars there just for once.

Comment: I can understand why you would want this, but central maven repo can be really annoying to get access and releases to. 
Have you checked the other common public repos such as jboss and springs?

Answer (score 1):

Same answer from [Maven and the JOGL library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962718/maven-and-the-jogl-library/13540171#13540171)

Jogamp now contains support for Maven, for the jogl components (jocl and joal support is forthcoming). As of 2.0-rc11, packages are pushed to Maven Central.

Just put this to your pom:

```
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
     <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
     <version>2.0-rc11</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
     <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
     <version>2.0-rc11</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Maven will pull all of the dependencies the next time you attempt to build the project.

[Read more here on the wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Maven)