# Running a RESTlet Tutorial, I'm receiving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm trying to run the first server tutorial on RESTlet [docs](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/319-restlet.html) but i'm getting errors even though i added the jars to my classpath. I added org.restlet.jar and org.restlet.ext.*

The code for the server is :

```
package test;

import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class Test extends ServerResource {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182  
        new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, Test.class).start();  
    }  

    @Get  
    public String toString() {  
        return "hello, world";  
    }  

}
```

And the errors i'm getting are:

```
    11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SocketFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:488)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.javamail.JavaMailClientHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:488)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jdbc.JdbcClientHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:488)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.lucene.SolrClientHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/request/SolrRequestHandler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:488)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.grizzly.HttpServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/grizzly/SelectorHandler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.grizzly.HttpsServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/grizzly/SelectorHandler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jetty.AjpServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jetty.HttpServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jetty.HttpsServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.netty.HttpServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.netty.HttpsServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.simple.HttpServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/simpleframework/http/core/Container
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.simpleframework.http.core.Container
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.simple.HttpsServerHelper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/simpleframework/http/core/Container
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:716)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:490)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:333)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.simpleframework.http.core.Container
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.javamail.JavaMailConverter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:714)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConverters(Engine.java:501)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:337)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 17 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jibx.JibxConverter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jibx/runtime/JiBXException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:714)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConverters(Engine.java:501)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:337)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 17 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine registerHelper
INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.json.JsonConverter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:714)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:749)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:789)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConverters(Engine.java:501)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:337)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.<init>(Restlet.java:99)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.<init>(Finder.java:147)
    at org.restlet.Server.<init>(Server.java:313)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 17 more
11/01/2011 1:22:08 PM org.restlet.engine.Engine createHelper
WARNING: No available server connector supports the required protocols: 'HTTP' . Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I got these errors too, because I was trying to run the packaged jar file with `java -jar myprogram.jar` and I wasn't telling maven in the `pom.xml` file to stuff all the dependencies into the jar file.  After I did, the "NoClassDefFoundErrors" were solved.  The solution concept was to instruct maven to package the dependencies in with the compiled jar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was Eclipse problem, i had to remove all the jars and only add org.restlet.jar and also clean the project. After i did that everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, just ran into the same problem and you saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I was also having the same problem in NetBeans IDE. I removed "org.restlet.ext.httpclient-2.1m1.jar" file from the project lib and no errors since then.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update that, from the latest `restlet-jee-2.0.10/lib` folder only copy the `org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar` and `org.restlet.jar`. That solved the problem in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

After running /selectableRestWebComponent/src/services/FirstServerResource.java as a web component in Eclipse. Include only org.restlet.jar in the build path library.

Make sure you clean the project and you may check 'build automatically' in the eclipse project tab.

Make sure you have a server running in the background or attached to the eclipse project, like Apache tomcat 6.2 for example.

The console should show the message 'Starting the internal [HTTP/1.1] server on port 8182' instead of showing all those errors you displayed in your question.

Open up a browser and go to the URL http://'localserverIPaddress':8182/test/tutorial and you should see the words hello, world displayed.