# printStackTrace() on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm a noob here.

On Appengine my servlet gives me a 500 error caused by this:

```
try{
classifiedTweet = SentAnalysis.classifytext("en", "I am happy");
}catch(MashapeClientException mce){
mce.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I comment it out it works, but I want to see why this is not working.

Help please

**Update 1**

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653040/cant-run-restlet-tutorial-2-0-first-server)

Just that the solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Comment out what? The whole thing?

Comment: I found something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653040/cant-run-restlet-tutorial-2-0-first-server)

Just that the solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see your stacktrace on the console itself. If you are uploading the app to appspot.com then you can go to appengine.google.com than to your application than go to logs. There you will find your stacktrace under the tag error.

Comment: I checked the logs and found this

    Error for /CbTest
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory
    at maptwit.SentimentAnalysisFree.classifytext(SentimentAnalysisFree.java:46)

I added the httpclient jar to the lib folder in war but no change

Help please

Comment: This is odd try to clean the project and try again. Go to project -> clean project. Also check your build path if by mistake you have 2 different versions of httpclient

Comment: I found something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653040/cant-run-restlet-tutorial-2-0-first-server)

Just that the solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

May be the method is trowing some other exception. Try catching a broader `Exception`.

```
try{
    classifiedTweet = SentAnalysis.classifytext("en", "I am happy");
} catch(MashapeClientException mce) {
    mce.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```