# Maven : what is the "runtime" scope purpose?

Tags: maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Compile- vs Run-time Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070570/understanding-compile-vs-run-time-dependencies)

I understand that a dependency with the "runtime" scope will be available at runtime and not at compile time. But I don't understand why you could want that! Why not simply use the "compile" scope instead?

The [docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) don't really help. Any idea?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070570/understanding-compile-vs-run-time-dependencies

Comment: Thanks Wes, that question is indeed really related. Sadly, I still don't understand! I would use "provided" for dependencies like servlet-api, not "runtime". I'd like to see a real-life example where using "runtime" is better than "compile" and "provided", if possible!

Comment: JDBC Driver mentioned by John Stauffer's answer is a good example.  Another example can be SLF4J.  You need only slf4j-api for compilation and you SHOULD avoid putting slf4j-log4j12 (or other kind of binding) as compile scope dependency.  slf4j-log4j12 is a good candidate for runtime dependency.

Comment: Why? Is it because slf4j-log4j12 should be in the app server's classpath? I already know the powers that be will veto this.

Comment: @user447607: No - this would (in theory) allow you to switch `slf4j` bindings without having to recompile the application.

Comment: this question is not duplicated.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

`runtime` is useful for dependencies required for unit tests and at runtime, but not at compile time. This may typically be dynamically loaded code, such as JDBC drivers, which are not directly referenced in the program code.

Setting dependency to `provided` ensures that there isn't an accidental dependency on the code, and also keeps the dependency from being transitive. So that, for example, if module A has a `provided` dependency on library X, and module B depends on module A, it does *not* inherit the dependency on library X. Using "runtime" or "compile" *would* cause B to depend on X.

Comment: But this link: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
Says that provide is not transitive. Is that wrong?

Comment: Ad transitive dependencies, I have an example of the contrary. After changing a dependency's scope from `runtime` to `provided`, its transitive dependencies are no longer part of my build.

Comment: Runtime *IS* transitive, even though that seems counter-intuitive. I really can't see any difference between compile and runtime, as far as how maven behaves.

Comment: I don't agree with the very last sentence, as stated here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6647178/704246.

Using "compile" would cause B to depend on X.
Using "provided" would cause B to have to explicitly redeclare dependency to X.

Comment: Contrary to what's mentioned at the end of the answer, the "provided" scope is NOT transitive.