# import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement not resolved

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jaxb, android-studio

I am using intellij and my code uses

`import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;`

It compiles and runs when I use command line. However when tried running a test class using the ide(intellij), it gives the error

`package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exists`

I have added the jaxb dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

What forces `intellij` not to detect this?

Comment: What is the version ? I guess it should be `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2` ! What version of Java you are using ?

Comment: Looks like it is problem of IDE.

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @Maverick were you able to solve this? I'm running into the issue myself

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check intellij , in the **Project Structure** dialog, go to **Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK**  , choose other version SDK like 1.8 and click **OK**

Answer (score 1):

Try to synchronize the IDE (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes even after adding the dependencies to the pom.xml file, maven fails to download the dependencies to your local machine. So we can have it downloaded by updating the  maven repository.

In case of intelliJ, in the **Settings/preference** dialog, go to **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build tools** -> **Maven** -> **Repositories**.
On the **Repositories** page, click **Update** to update maven repositories.

If you're using eclipse, **Right click** your project -> **maven** -> **update project**.
In the update project window, select the recently modified projects and click **Ok**.

After updating, check if you could import your packages.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ends up here.
My dependency scope was listed as 'runtime' and changing it to 'provided' meant it downloaded the dependency

I'm coming from a python background and trying to debug something and have no idea what i'm doing though, so hopefully i haven't created a major issue... ([this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272499/maven-what-is-the-runtime-scope-purpose) talks a bit about the difference)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

with Eclipse Spring boot
i only use

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Reason? my coworker delete swagger jar

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with javax vs jakarta

---

Try using this dependency

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - his dependency works fine, it's the IDE that fails.

Comment: @Chaoz did you try this dependency instead of that one? Coz I was facing the same issue but this one works fine.