# cannot resolve "org.h2.tools.Server"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded some code from net and opened it in Eclipse. The problem is 
my Eclipse says

> The import org.h2 cannot be resolved

for following code:

```
import org.h2.tools.Server;
```

I am learning Java and that was a sample code. I'm using jdk1.8.0_40. I cleaned my project but it still there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this means your code requires a so called 3rd party library which is not part of the jdk. H2 is a java based database. To remove this error, download the current version of the h2 database driver and do the following in eclipse - open context menu on your project, choose the properties ( last entry). Search for "build path", choose the third tab and add the download driver (should be a jar file, maybe packed in a zip) to your project.

Cannot better describe this now, I am on my mobile.

Comment: Perfect. Please mark as answered to close this question.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I changed the `h2` dependency on `pom.xml`

It was

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I removed the `scope` and it found the `Server` package

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

A good explanation on why this is happening on runtime here:
[Maven : what is the "runtime" scope purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272499/maven-what-is-the-runtime-scope-purpose)