# Database connection on H2 for Spring Petclinic project

Tags: spring

I've cloned and installed the [spring petclinic project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git)

It's working correctly, but I don't understand if and how I can access the H2 db.

I see that in application.properties there is no username nor password, nor dbname.

Does this mean I can't access it from /h2-console? because maybe it's embedded?

Is there another setting (?server?) in order to access it? Which will be the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution [How to enable H2 Database Server Mode in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830010/how-to-enable-h2-database-server-mode-in-spring-boot)

Basically, it removes runtime scope from h2 dependency in pom.xml and starts the H2 as a Bean in the Spring Application.

Only extra thing is that I have to read the Spring starting log to find the message

```
o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:27cca538-56b1-49d6-9b63-317e28c3e4a9'
```

And then use the jdbc URL in the console with user "sa" and empty password.

Don't understand it very much but it's working...