# Cannot connect to H2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

I have been getting struggle to connect H2 database from a Spring Boot app by using the following connection string as mentioned on [Database URL Overview](http://h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=server&search=server#connection_modes) section:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/test-db
```

I also tried many different combination for tcp (server mode) connection, but still get error e.g. "*Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out: localhost:9092"* when running Spring Boot app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    // code omitted
    
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }
}
```

So, how can I fix this problem and connect to H2 database via server mode?

Comment: Have you started the db server? See http://h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html or check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847035/2290153

Comment: Amigo, I solved the problem by applying the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256295/how-to-access-in-memory-h2-database-of-one-spring-boot-application-from-another/43276769#43276769) page, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused.

H2 can run in two different 'modes'.

#### Local mode

Local mode means H2 'just works', and you access this mode with the `file:` thing in the JDBC connect URL. The JDBC driver itself does all the database work, as in, it opens files, writes data, it does it all. *There is no 'database server'* at all. Or, if you prefer, the JDBC driver is its own server though it opens no ports.

### Server mode

In this case **you need a (separate) JVM and separately fire up H2 in server mode** and then you can use the same library (still `h2.jar`) to serve as a JDBC server. In this mode, the two things are **completely separate** - if you want, you can run h2.jar on one machine to be the server, and run the same h2.jar on a completely different machine just to connect to the other H2 machine. The database server machine does the bulk of the work, with the 'client' H2 just being the JDBC driver. H2 is no different than e.g. mysql or postgres in such a mode: You have one 'app' / JVM process that runs as a database engine, allowing multiple different processes, even coming from completely different machines halfway around the world if you want to, to connect to it.

You access this mode with the `tcp:` thing in the JDBC string.

If you really want, you can run this mode and still have it all on a single machine, even a single JVM, but why would you want to? Whatever made you think this will 'solve lock errors' wouldn't be fixed by running all this stuff on a single JVM. There are only two options:

- You're mis-analysing the problem.
- You really do have multiple separate JVM processes (either one machine with 2 `java` processes in the activity monitor / `ps auxww` output / task manager, or 2+ machines) all trying to connect to a single database in which case you certainly do need this, yes.

### How to do server mode right

You most likely want a separate JVM that starts before and that hosts the h2 database; it needs to run before the 'client' JVMs (the ones that will connect to it) start running. Catalina is not the 'server' you are looking for, it is `org.h2.tools.Server`, and if it says 'not found' you need to fix your maven imports. This needs be a separate JVM (you COULD write code that goes: Oh, hey, there isn't a separate JVM running with the h2 server so I'll start it in-process right here right now, but that means that process needs to stay in the air forever, which is just weird. Hence, you *want* a separate JVM process for this).

You haven't explained what you're doing. But, let's say what you're doing is this:

- I have a CI script that fires up multiple separate JVMs, some in parallel even, which runs a bunch of integration and unit tests in parallel.
- Even though they run in parallel (or perhaps intentionally so), you all want to run this off of a single DB. This is usually a really bad idea (you want tests to be isolated; that running them on their own continues to behave identically. You don't want a test to fail in a way that can only be reproduced if you run the same batch of 18 separate tests using the same run code, where one unrelated test fails in a specific fashion, whilst it's Tuesday, a full moon, and Beethoven is playing in your music player, and it's warmer than 24º in the room affecting the CPU's throttling, of course. Which is exactly what tends to happen if you try to re-use resources in multiple tests!) – still, you somehow really want this.
- ... then, edit the CI script to first Launch a JVM that hosts a H2 server, and once that's up and running, presumably run a process that fills this database with test data, and once that's done, then run all tests in parallel, and once those are all done, shut down the JVM, and delete the DB file.

Exactly how to do the third part is a separate question - if you need help with that, ask a new question and name the relevant tool(s) you are using to run this stuff, paste the config files, etc.

Comment: What about answering the question regarding to my problem?

Comment: @Jonathan This answer fully details exactly what is going wrong. I have re-read your question. I guess this answer confuses you? Please elucidate what about it, or which question you feel it doesn't answer. To be specific: You __ARE__ connecting to the H2 server exactly as you intend. However, __it isn't running!__

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem by applying the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256295/how-to-access-in-memory-h2-database-of-one-spring-boot-application-from-another/43276769#43276769) page, thanks. By the way, voted up ;)