# Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run the spring boot application not able to access H2 database

```
   spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bitsapi;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
```

these how my pom.xml i have added dependency's

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.9</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

when i run the the application am getting failed to bind properties

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-13 12:01:39,685 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driverclassname
    Value: org.h2.Driver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 9):

I guess you use the Spring Boot Starter JPA. This dependency already comes which the Hikari Connection Pooling dependency and I would suggest to remove it from your `pom.xml` and let Spring Boot manage the versions.

Once you removed the manual import of the Hikari CP, make sure to have `runtime` scope of your H2:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Short explanation of what the `runtime` scope is doing:

> runtime is useful for dependencies required for unit tests and at
>   runtime, but not at compile time. This may typically be dynamically
>   loaded code, such as JDBC drivers, which are not directly referenced
>   in the program code ([Maven : what is the "runtime" scope purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272499/maven-what-is-the-runtime-scope-purpose))

Answer (score 3):

I was getting above error,
when trying to bring-up my spring-boot application in intellij.
The mistake I was making was
After changing in "build.gradle" file,
(ie adding runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2'))
I did NOT do the "Reload gradle project",
that's why above error was coming.
Once completed "Reload gradle project", above error was gone.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31020346)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spelling and case of the letters - upper case or lower case.
After googling all over the world , I found that I typed 'datasource' instead of 'dataSource' in my application.properties. I am new to IntelliJ and don't know why it is not giving any auto-suggestions.