# NoClassDefFoundError when running flink with kafka connector

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to stream data from kafka using flink. My code compiles without error but on running I get the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/apache/flink/streaming/util/serialization/DeserializationSchema
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.DeserializationSchema
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

My POM dependency list is as follows:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>
```

The java code that I am trying to run just subscribes to a kafka topic called 'streamer':

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.DeserializationSchema;

public class StreamConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "samplegroup");

        DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>("streamer", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

        messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;
                        @Override
                        public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                                return "Streamed data: " + value;
                        }
                }).print();
        env.execute();
}
}
```

System information:
1. Kafka version: 0.9.0.1
2. Flink version: 1.3.2
3. OpenJDK version: 1.8

Although I am using maven, I do not think this is any maven issue because I get the same error even when I try without maven. I manually downloaded all the necessary .jar files to a folder and specified that folder path with the -cp option while compiling with javac. I get the same error as above during runtime but no errors during compile time.

Comment: If in IntelliJ: "**Note on IntelliJ: To make the applications run within IntelliJ IDEA it is necessary to tick the Include dependencies with "Provided" scope box in the run configuration. If this option is not available (possibly due to using an older IntelliJ IDEA version), then a simple workaround is to create a test that calls the applications main() method.**" https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/project-configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason and it seems like a really silly error now. In my case the jar packages weren't available at run time. I ended up not using maven at all. I compiled with `javac -cp <path_to_jar_files>` and executed again with `java -cp <path_to_jar_files>`

Answer (score 3):

Try removing **scope** if you have specified it some where in pom file, as it restricts scope of class files during run-time

[Limit Scope in POM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for)

Answer (score 2):

The cause can also be that if the job is started via Intellij, the dependencies with "provided" are not included in the classpath. [This is a common problem.](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/flinkdev/ide_setup/#examples-fail-with-a-noclassdeffounderror-for-flink-classes)

Go to the Run / Debug Configuration in Intellij, click on "Modify options" and select "Add dependencies with 'provided' scope to classpath".

[image: Option that should be checked]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first problem with your pom is that you use different version for your flink imports. Try to use newer version `1.3.2` for all flink modules. This error often occurs when you use incompatible or multiple versions of libraries.

Try using fallowing dependencies (assuming you are using scala 2.11):

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

If you still have the same problem post example code so I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I tried that but the versions mentioned here are the latest available.

Comment: flink-streaming-core no longer exists and is subsumed by flink-streaming-java_<scala version>. flink-clients also has a scala suffix now.

Comment: I tried with these dependencies and still have the same error. I have added the java code above.

Comment: @raviabhiram I created new maven project in Intellij with exactly those dependencies. I set up kafla and kafka producer as in oficail tutorial https://data-artisans.com/blog/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to . With the difference that I downloaded newer version of kafka from the same site `kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0`. And everything works for me.

Comment: Thanks @abalcerek. I just figured out the reason. In my case the jar packages weren't available at run time. I ended up not using maven at all. I compiled with `javac -cp <path_to_jar_files>` and executed again with `java -cp <path_to_jar_files>`.

Comment: @raviabhiram You can use maven jar plugin or shade plugin to build fat jar with all needed dependencies if you require to submit jar to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

> NoClassDefFoundError when running flink with kafka connector

Your code code compiles and You are getting NoClassDefFoundError, I think one of 
your dependency library missing it's **Compile Dependencies** or **Runtime Dependencies** during auto download process by maven .pom

So probably It's the root causes You getting NoClassDefFoundError

> Solution: clean and build