# Flink CEP: Import Errors and Type Mismatches in Stroke Risk Alarm Application

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm working on a project that uses Apache Flink's Complex Event Processing (CEP) to create a stroke risk alarm system. However, I'm encountering several issues in my Java code, and I'm seeking help to resolve them.

**Code Sample:**

Here's my Java code in the `StrokeRiskAlarm` class:

```java
package hes.cs63.CEPMonitor;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.cep.CEP;
import org.apache.flink.cep.Pattern;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternSelectFunction;
import org.apache.flink.cep.conditions.SimpleCondition;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.config.StartupMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.config.TableKafkaConnectorOptions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class StrokeRiskAlert {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "stroke-risk-group");

        // Use KafkaSource instead of FlinkKafkaConsumer
        DataStream<String> patientData = env.fromSource(
                KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                        .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                        .setGroupId("stroke-risk-group")
                        .setTopic("patient-data-topic")
                        .setProperties(properties)
                        .setDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                        .setStartingOffsets(StartupMode.EARLIEST)
                        .build(),
                "Kafka Source");

        Pattern<String, ?> highRiskPattern = Pattern.<String>begin("first")
                .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String value) {
                        return getValue(value) > 3;
                    }
                });

        DataStream<Map<String, List<String>>> patternStream = CEP.pattern(
                patientData,
                highRiskPattern);

        DataStream<String> strokeRiskAlerts = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String select(Map<String, List<String>> pattern) throws Exception {
                String userId = pattern.get("first").get(0).split(",")[0].trim();
                int risk = getTotalRisk(pattern.get("first").get(0), pattern.get("middle").get(0),
                        pattern.get("last").get(0));
                return "Stroke Risk Alert: Patient ID - " + userId + ", Risk Level - " + risk;
            }
        });

        strokeRiskAlerts.print();

        env.execute("Stroke Risk Alert Job");
    }

    private static double getValue(String value) {
        // Parse the input value and extract the relevant data for risk calculation
        String[] parts = value.split(",");
        String type = parts[2].trim();
        double measurementValue = Double.parseDouble(parts[3].trim());

        // Implement your logic to check high stroke risk for different measurements
        if (type.equals("HR")) {
            // HeartMeasurement risk calculation logic
            int risk = 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 50 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 40 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue >= 91 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue >= 110 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue >= 131 ? 1 : 0;
            return risk;
        } else if (type.equals("SBP")) {
            // BloodPressureMeasurement risk calculation logic
            int risk = 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 110 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 100 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 90 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue >= 220 ? 3 : 0;
            return risk;
        } else if (type.equals("TEMP")) {
            // TempMeasurement risk calculation logic
            int risk = 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 36 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue <= 35 ? 2 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue >= 38.1 ? 1 : 0;
            risk += measurementValue >= 39.1 ? 1 : 0;
            return risk;
        }

        // Default risk calculation
        return 0;
    }

    private static int getTotalRisk(String firstValue, String middleValue, String lastValue) {
        // Calculate the total risk based on the values of the first, middle, and last
        // measurements
        int firstRisk = getValue(firstValue);
        int middleRisk = getValue(middleValue);
        int lastRisk = getValue(lastValue);

        return firstRisk + middleRisk + lastRisk;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

```
I'm encountering the following errors in my code:

1. "The import org.apache.flink.cep.Pattern cannot be resolved" (Line 5)
2. "The import org.apache.flink.cep.conditions cannot be resolved" (Line 7)
3. "The import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaSource cannot be resolved" (Line 10)
4. "The import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.config.TableKafkaConnectorOptions cannot be resolved" (Line 12)
5. "KafkaSource cannot be resolved" (Line 28)
6. "Pattern cannot be resolved to a type" (Line 38)
7. "Pattern cannot be resolved" (Line 38)
8. "SimpleCondition cannot be resolved to a type" (Line 39)
9. "The method filter(String) of type new SimpleCondition<String>(){} must override or implement a supertype method" (Line 41)
10. "The method select(new PatternSelectFunction<String,String>(){}) is undefined for the type DataStream<Map<String,List<String>>>" (Line 50)
11. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int" (Lines 106, 107, 108)
12. "Unknown word 'Flink'" (Line 26)
```

**What I've Tried:**

I've already added the necessary dependencies to my `pom.xml` file, including Apache Flink and Kafka dependencies, with the correct versions. However, these errors persist, and I'm not sure how to resolve them.

#### pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-kafka-stroke-risk</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Flink Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-cep</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache Kafka Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Other Dependencies -->
    <!-- Add other dependencies your project may require here -->

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve these import errors and type mismatches in my Apache Flink CEP-based stroke risk alarm application. Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you having this problem when running Flink in an IDE, or in a real Flink cluster?

Comment: Having this problem while running flink in the IDE

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74830262/2000823