# How can I resolve my class from a different jar with same structure like another

Tags: java, selenium, jar, phantomjs, classnotfoundexception

How can I resolve my class from a different jar with same structure like another

> **Note** : Though the jars in question contains the word **selenium** but the question here have no direct relation with **selenium**

Till a few days back **PhantomJSDriver** was released bundled along with `selenium-server-standalone-v.v.v.jar`. So my Class was working fine as:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public class A_PhantomJS
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
          File path=new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
          System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
          WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }
}
```

Now `selenium-server-standalone-v.v.v.jar` doesn't bundles the jar for **PhantomJSDriver** dependency.

So I have downloaded the jar `phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar` and added as an external jar to my project.

You can see the structure of the `phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar` is similar to what it was earlier when it was bundled with `selenium-server-standalone-v.v.v.jar`

[image: PhantomJSDriver]

Now, though my Class gets resolved through:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
```

But I am facing a Runtime exception of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:89)
    at demo.A_PhantomJS.main(A_PhantomJS.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Proxies
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Line 15 being:

```
WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
```

As per the error I have searched for `org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Proxies` within the phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar unable to find any clue.

[image: NoClassDefFoundError]

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the Question is Answered in a [User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7GALk-zPi-4) by none other than [Simon Stewart](https://github.com/shs96c).

> **Answer** : **`There's a version of phantomjsdriver ('com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.4.4') that appears to be kept up to date with latest selenium releases. I'd suggest using that.`**

Here is the snapshot of Simon's comment :

[image: Simon_Stewart]

Here is the working solution:
[image: PhantomJSDriver_solved]

Answer (score 3):

This jar includes *org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Proxies*, try adding it to your classpath:

https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.4.0/selenium-api-2.4.0.jar

If you miss other classes, you can search them by classname with Advanced Search on Maven Central Repository: https://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav

Comment: Thanks, Does that mean if I don't bundle a particular jar and later add the jar as an external dependency, I may require to add further more dependency jars?

Comment: It depends on the differences between the original jar with bundled dependencies, and the new jar without bundled dependencies: do you know exactly all their differences, and what the new jar is missing? If you dont know for sure (like you dont have access to release notes)  then yes, you could find out than more dependencies jars were needed

Comment: Thanks again. Your Answer did help me to perform the required debugging with the olden jars. I have added the exact Answer as a new Answer.

Answer (score 2):

The exception tells that the required class was not found in the classpath.
As you have mentioned that you are adding `PhantomJSDriver-jar` as an external dependency. Make sure you have the correct scope for the jar and it is bundled when you package your application.

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for) to get better understanding of the scope.

Comment: Thanks @Ravik Your answer was in the right direction.I have added the exact Answer as a new Answer.

Answer (score 1):

even i had the same issue. try the below code. It worked for me;

```
    WebDriver driver;
    File src = new File("//PATH");
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
            new String[] { "--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes" });
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

    driver.get("URL");
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. My Question is not regarding the _code_ but **configuration**