# How to initialize PhantomJS browser through Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to use the phantomjsdriver in Java to build a Webspider. I am using Selenium Version 3.11.0, PhantomJS 2.1.1 and the phantomjsdriver Version 1.2.1. 
When i am executing my code I get the following error Message.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

```
package Masterarbeit.Crawler;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public class Test {

    public String Test(){
        File path=new File("/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(); 
        return "successful";

    }
}
```

My OS is Linux Mint 18 Sarah, does anybody know a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till a few days back **PhantomJSDriver** was released bundled along with *selenium-server-standalone-v.v.v.jar* so we were able to resolve the method **`PhantomJSDriver()`** through `import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;` from the *selenium-server-standalone-x.y.z.jar*

But now, **selenium-server-standalone-v.v.v.jar** doesn't bundles the jar for **PhantomJSDriver** dependency. So you have to obtain a version of **phantomjsdriver** from (`com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.4.4`) that appears to be kept up to date with latest selenium releases.

Download and add the **phantomjsdriver-1.4.4.jar** to your *Project*.

Use the following code block and execute your `@Test` :

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public class phantomJS_launch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


          File path=new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
          System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
          WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();

    }

}
```

**Important** : **`PhantomJSDriver()`** still resolves through **`import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;`**

Console Output :

```
Apr 25, 2018 9:24:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: C:\Utility\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe
Apr 25, 2018 9:24:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 25078
Apr 25, 2018 9:24:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=25078, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\Java_PhantomJS\phantomjsdriver.log]
Apr 25, 2018 9:24:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2018-04-25T15:54:19.809Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 25078
[INFO  - 2018-04-25T15:54:20.263Z] Session [ea9746f0-48a0-11e8-8b6b-f78193ae50b0] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2018-04-25T15:54:20.263Z] Session [ea9746f0-48a0-11e8-8b6b-f78193ae50b0] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2018-04-25T15:54:20.263Z] Session [ea9746f0-48a0-11e8-8b6b-f78193ae50b0] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-8-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2018-04-25T15:54:20.264Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: ea9746f0-48a0-11e8-8b6b-f78193ae50b0
Apr 25, 2018 9:24:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Google
[INFO  - 2018-04-25T15:54:22.023Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**How can I resolve my class from a different jar with same structure like another**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192621/how-can-i-resolve-my-class-from-a-different-jar-with-same-structure-like-another)

Comment: Worked perfect for me. Thanks a lot.