# Java Selenium error with Firefox-Portable

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, marionette, geckodriver

I am struggling to get our integration tests back up and running after updating our heavily outdated FirefoxPortable to the newest version 68.0.1. 
I was understood to use the geckodriver.  But I keep getting the following message.

**Error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException(Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

**Code:**

```
    if (OS.isFamilyWindows()) {

        FirefoxBinary binary =
                new FirefoxBinary(new File(binPath + "/firefoxWindows/FirefoxPortable.exe"));
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", binPath + "/geckoWindows/geckodriver.exe");
        firefoxOptions.setBinary(binary);
        ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
    }
```

Our integration tests will be executed on a shared Linux Jenkins test server. For now I am using Windows.

I would like to keep using a portable version of Firefox to prevent conflicts with other teams using the same machine. Also the installation of Docker is unfortunately no option.

We are using Java.version: '1.8.0_171' and we are too late in the release to switch to a later version.

Should I switch to Chrome?

I am in need of a quick solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using **FirefoxPortable v68.0.1** presumably you are using the latest release of *Selenium v3.141.59* thus using *GeckoDriver* is mandatory. It is observed that using the following code block *GeckoDriver* with the help of **marionette** is able to initiate the **FirefoxPortable v68.0.1** browser but soon crashes with an error.

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;


  public class A_Portable_Firefox {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.setBinary("C:\\FirefoxPortable\\FirefoxPortable.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Error Stacktrace:

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
  Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
  System info: host: 'DEBANJAN', ip: '192.168.1.125', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
  Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: FirefoxPortable]

---

### Analysis

As per the discussion [GeckoDriver v0.23.0 is unable to initiate a new session through FirefoxPortable](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1443) @andreastt clearly mentioned:

> I’m afraid Firefox Portable is not supported by geckodriver.

@whimboo further added:

> If the splash screen (or what this is) is blocking Firefox from fully starting up, then Marionette will not be enabled.

Comment: Is there an alternative I can use, that does not require be to have administrative rights on the test server?

Comment: @Jonas_Hess Ideally, Selenium tests should be executed with non-root user/privileges.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot install a browser on the test server. So I was hoping to find a solution that does not require me to do so.

Comment: Install the _Portable Firefox Browser_ on an external device, e.g. pen drive or external hard-disk and continue the test execution.

Comment: But you just said that FirefoxPortable is not supported and will run into an error. It’s not that I don’t have access to the filesystem.  I just can’t install an additional browser on that machine, so I would like to use a portable browser, as using it does not require root privileges.  Is there a way to get selenium up and running with a portable browser?

Comment: Okay, possibly you have to look at either [**PhantomJS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192621/how-can-i-resolve-my-class-from-a-different-jar-with-same-structure-like-another) or  [**HtmlUnit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724856/htmlunitdriver-does-not-load-javascript-when-navigating-a-page-from-an-url/53744963#53744963) which doesn't needs an installation

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your tests through jenkins on linux server, i.e jenkins is executing tests on a linux machine,you need to run tests in headless mode of firefox.

Also you need to install xvfb on linux machine.