# Jar file Error because of simple JSON dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar, json-simple

I have a maven project that uses the json-simple library. When I create jar file using

```
mvn clean
mvn test
mvn install
```

and try to run the jar file using `java -jar target/Game2048-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get an error as shown below:

[image]

My pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Game2048_GId</groupId>
<artifactId>Game2048</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there anything wrong with my pom file? There are multiple classes for the project (but just 1 main class)

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot it seems you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`, which is mainly due to **scope**,`scope` is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency, and also to affect the **classpath** used for various build tasks.

Try Adding `scope` to **json-simple** dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I think the problem is with `scope` , please try changing the scope to "`compile`" or "`test`" after `provided` in case if it dont work still.

**FYI**

[What is <scope> under <dependency> in pom.xml for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for)

---

Edit: Change `provided` to `compile`.

Comment: Or simply removing the scope tag from prom will also work as the default scope is compile only

Answer (score 0):

try with java -cp {absolute path of your m2 dir or jar library} -jar {your jar}.jar.
The reason for no class Def found error is always that jar is not part of your classpath , -cp option will add the json simple jar and its dependencies  to the classpath and your error would be solved  .

Comment: not always, why to hardcode stuffs when you have maven??

Comment: What is the other reason for noclassdeferror other than class not present on classpath or inaccessible by jvm?? And what is the hardcoding here !!

Comment: In real application projects it could happen that dependency jar that you have to consume is still under development and you have only interface jar  for it , in that case maven and nexus repos wont be able to provide you the implementation jar , that is why maven scope provided would be used , and in production you can give the impl jar by -cp option .Agree ideally depenedency management should be done via maven but it is not always best fit for all problems .