# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/bind/JsonbBuilder even after adding javaee-api to dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am using maven with netbeans. Whenever I run the program it gives me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception even after adding `javaee-api 8.0` to dependencies.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <debug>false</debug>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I can see the `javax.json.bind.*` in Dependencies. I don't get why am I not able to run the program. Any pointers?

Comment: please add which class exactly you got `NoClassDefFoundError` for

Comment: try to add 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>`
 as dependency

Comment: @Spara I have even downloaded the source code along with binaries of javaee 8 and I can see `javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder` in dependencies. My point is, why do I get the error even after adding dependency to `javaee-api`?

Comment: @star67 `javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder`

Comment: you add javaee-api dependecy in the **provided** scope which is not adding library in runtime to your libs. so you need to add the dependency which I said in the previous comment which is adding in the compile scope which is the default one

Comment: @Spara I had to add `javax.json`, `javax.json.bind`, `org.eclipse.yasson` and `org.glassfish.javax.json` in order to make it work.

Comment: @Spara It will work for sure. Can I just use `javaee` with some other scope to make it work?

Comment: Hello, with Netbeans, have you created an enterprise application or a web application or just a java appliction?

Comment: @M.Ismail Just a java app using maven.

Comment: Let me describe it for you as an answer

Comment: try delete the scope provided in the pom.xml file.

Comment: @Spara Sure :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face is that you need to add libraries which you use in your project manually. As you said `javaee-api` has dependency to `javax.json.bind.*` but the scope of that is **provided** which means that it will provide by your jdk or a container (application server for example) in the runtime( for more information about scopes check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230903/4431053)). So you need to add libraries you need as **compile** scope(the default scope)  which you need them in runtime.

Comment: One last question. Why can't I add `compile` scope to `javaee-api` and get it to work?

Comment: Because the default value of scope is compile, so it is added by default.

Comment: @baba It will add lots of library to your libs which is not good and also they should provide by your container.