# After adding dependency, can't import dependency class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After adding a dependency to my POM.xml file and rebuilding with mvn dependency:resolve I am unable to import the dependency in my class. For example, I added the security dependency to my pom.xml file, but I can't import the Spring Boot Security package from org.springframework... 
It says the symbol can't be resolved.

I have tried rebuilding my project but it doesn't work. I can only import if I reinitialize my project with Spring Intializr with the security dependency.

My POM:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.drkalamlibrary</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-backend</name>
    <description>Presidential Library </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Class I Am Trying to Use Security Dependency In:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .permitAll()
    .and().csrf().disable();
   }
}
```

Whenever I try and import the security class from SpringBoot, a red underline appears under the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import your spring security dependencies after removing the `test` scope. Like this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The `test` scope only loads the dependencies for testing phases, like it's mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for) post. That's why you can't load your imports for spring security.