# Cannot access Java library

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pom.xml

**Note:** I'm asking/answering this question because I didn't find my solution anywhere else.

I am getting the following error message in my ServerMain.java file when I try running my maven project:

> cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool

I have the jar file, I added `org.eclipse.jett:jetty-util` in my pom.xml file but no matter how I add the library I still don't have access to it. Here is how it is included in my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.5.v20140505</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. I needed to remove the `<scope>` tag from the xml. I'm not sure how it got on there in the first place since the maven site does not limit the scope for [jetty-util](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/9.1.5.v20140505). The dependency needs to be included like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.5.v20140505</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: [Further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for).