# Java error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException

Tags: java

I know that there are a lot of questions related to this, but I messed up everything.

I am running my main class and receiving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
```

In my project I have several pom.xml files and I checked that all of them contains:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230903

Comment: oke.. `<scope>provided</scope>` means: you/someone will (have to) provide them!:)..at runtime;)

Comment: @xerx593 Ok. fool me do not get it. Where I can read about this? What will be the steps? I am not asking direct answer as you can see, but at least path to fix it :(

Comment: [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) a good entry point... beyond that it is good-important to know/understand your "dev(runtime) stack" as your "dependency structure"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you have "several" pom files. But assuming you're actually using one of those pom.xml's and you have that dependency in it, the issue is this:

You've indicated that your dependency is `provided`:

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

This means that Maven expects the runtime environment to provide that dependency. You often see it when you're running in a web server environment (eg. Tomcat, Wildfly, etc.) where there will be additional libraries provided by that environment.

In this case, you either need to provide that dependency at runtime, or update your pom to *not* expect the dependency to be provided and rebuild. Deleting that `<scope>` is sufficient.

More information about dependency scope can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: As Roddy said, if your runtime (Spring, Quarkus, Liberty, etc.) does not also use, i.e. provide, the required library, then it can't be defined by you as "provided".