# Java throws a "No suitable driver" exception

Tags: java, docker, maven, jdbc

I am trying to connect a Java program to a Database on my Docker Localhost.
I am developing in VSCode with Maven to manage my dependencies.

To do this, I added the JDBC driver "mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar" to my resource folder and included it in the pom dependencies.

When trying to run the program, it throws a driver Exception:
**Fehlercode: 0
SQL State: 08001
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/aufgabe_4**

I looked through various other questions on this topic and tried some things, like adding `Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");`
before attempting to open the connection. This however lead to another exception:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException
at com.datenbanken.aufgabe4.DBVerbindung.verbinden(DBVerbindung.java:15)**

I apologize if this has been answered already, but I can't find any solution that works for me.

Here is my source code:

```
package com.datenbanken.aufgabe4;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBVerbindung {
    private Connection con = null;
    private String dbAdresse = "localhost:3306";
    private String dbInstanz = "aufgabe_4";

    public void verbinden(String nutzer, String passwort) {
        try {
            //Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://" + dbAdresse + "/"
                    + dbInstanz, nutzer, passwort);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ausnahmeAusgeben(e);
        }
    }

    private void ausnahmeAusgeben(SQLException e) {
        while (e != null) {
            System.err.println("Fehlercode: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("SQL State: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.err.println(e);
            e = e.getNextException();
        }
    }

    public void verbindungTrennen() {
        if (con == null) {
            System.out.println("keine Verbindung vorhanden");
            return;
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ausnahmeAusgeben(e);
        }
    }

    public void verbindungAnalysieren() {
        if (con == null) {
            System.out.println("keine Verbindung vorhanden");
            return;
        }
        try {
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("DB-Name: " + dbmd.getDatabaseProductName()
                    + "\nDB-Version: " + dbmd.getDatabaseMajorVersion()
                    + "\nDB-Release: " + dbmd.getDriverMinorVersion()
                    + "\nTransaktionen erlaubt: " + dbmd.supportsTransactions()
                    + "\nbeachtet GroßKlein: " + dbmd.storesMixedCaseIdentifiers()
                    + "\nunterstützt UNION: " + dbmd.supportsUnion()
                    + "\nmax. Prozedurname: " + dbmd.getMaxProcedureNameLength());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ausnahmeAusgeben(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        DBVerbindung db = new DBVerbindung();
        db.verbinden("root", "bitnami");
        db.verbindungAnalysieren();
        db.verbindungTrennen();
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.datenbanken.aufgabe4</groupId>
    <artifactId>aufgabe4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datenbanken.aufgabe4</groupId>
    <artifactId>aufgabe4</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</project>
```

and here is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

EDIT1: Updated pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.datenbanken.aufgabe4</groupId>
    <artifactId>aufgabe4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client  (Dependency direkt von Maven)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>   


</project>
```

Comment: You say the database is running "on the Docker localhost".  In Docker generally each container is its own `localhost`.  Where is the application running?  The database?  How is Docker involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POM says

```
<scope>system</scope>
```

And it won't get included into the jar. You must provide the driver in the setup of the container or include it into the artifact with

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

Why you do not include the dependeny from maven central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.7.3 ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried changing the scope to runtime (which is hopefully done by changing just that one line) and i tried getting the dependency directly from maven central (I added that under EDIT1).
Both still lead to the "no suitable driver" error though... Do you have any other ideas what may cause the problem?

Comment: Sorry if this is considered trivial, but I am new to this and dont know where to start...

Comment: @Ehrenmann Read [the doc](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies) and [*What is <scope> under <dependency> in pom.xml for?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26975818/642706).