# Apache Spark Java examples with IntelliJ: sql package does not exist when make

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, apache-spark, classpath

When I create a **Scala SBT project** in IntelliJ, **everything works fine**. I set up the jar dependencies and I can run the examples.

But if I create a Java project and try to run:

> Error:(29, 28) java:
>   C:\workspace-java\SparkExamples\src\org\apache\spark\examples\sql\JavaSparkSQL.java:29:
>   package org.apache.spark.sql does not exist

I added that jar to module dependencies which contains the class in the error message. In the IDE everything seems fine, I can navigate into the JavaSparkSQL class. But when I make, it's doesn't find that class.

I added the jar to CLASSPATH, and also copy to JAVA_HOME/jdk/jre/lib/ext.

What do you think what do I wrong? What should I check?

**UPDATE:**
**The problem is only with org.apache.spark.sql package.** There are other packages what I can use. (org.apache.spark.SparkConf; org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD; etc.)

**UPDATE 2.:**
I gave a try to Eclipse Mars, and it was completed successfully the first time. So it is an IntelliJ specific problem.

**UPDATE 3.:**

Something wrong with the jar file which comes with Apache Spark (spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar).

Eclipse has no problem with this jar.

I found that **when I delete an irrelevant file from jar** ("about.html") then the **problem is gone**. IntelliJ see every package from the modified jar.

How is this possible?

Comment: do you have spark-sql jar in your classpath when you are running the jar? ex :http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.4.1/spark-sql_2.10-1.4.1.jar

Comment: Thank you for your great comment Jishnu Prathap. Based on your comment I have made a workaround for this problem.
After I added spark-sql.jar then the original error gone but another appeared: 

class file for org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType not found

The original jar (spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar) contains everything and more than spark-sql.jar so I copied every class into spark-sql.jar from the assembly jar.
And it worked!

But I don't understand the core of the problem. Why everything works in Eclipse without that spark-sql.jar and why not in IntelliJ.

Comment: What is the scope of dependency you have added? by default its compile scope.If you make it runtime i think it should work in Intellij too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070570/can-a-program-depend-on-a-library-during-compilation-but-not-runtime

Comment: The scope is compile but the error comes when IntelliJ compile so it should be good. (I tried with runtime without success).

Comment: One more fun thing:

I copy spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar and rename to spark-assembly-cut.jar and in this new jar I delete everything but the sql package. When I add this new jar eveything works fine!
So it seems IntelliJ cannot read well this assembly.jar. Maybe there are too much content in it? I don't know.