# How to make jar of jars using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven)

I am beginner in maven and would like to build a jar containing dependency jars in it using maven. But, I could not do so. Kindly help me about it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other question is about putting all dependencies in a single jar, by any means. This question is specifically about making a jar of jars. In this case, the jars must not be unpacked into a flat structure, but retained as distinct jar files (much like the war file format). This is clear from sridhar's comment to the accepted answer from JHS -- it doesn't do what he wants.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would to include the following in your `pom.xml` file.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>MainClass with the packages</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks for you advise but I would like to make a jar say jarFinal.jar contains jar1.jar, jar2.jar, jar3.jar etc. The suggestions given makes one jar extracting all class files from the dependency jars. I would like to make a jar of jars without unpacking class files.

Comment: @sridhar Could you make jar in jar?
Does this accepted answer make "jar in jar"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it unpacks the jars. The closest answer is Hip Hip Array's suggestion to use One-Jar as it does actually maintain the nesting of jars.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to create a single jar that contains your application and it's required libraries, there are two ways (that I know of) to do that. The first is [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), which uses a special classloader to allow the nesting of jars. The second is [UberJar](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/uberjar.html), (or [Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)), which explodes the included libraries and puts all the classes in the top-level jar.

I should also mention that UberJar and Shade are plugins for Maven1 and Maven2 respectively. As mentioned below, you can also use the assembly plugin (which in reality is much more powerful, but much harder to properly configure).

Comment: Thanks for you advise but I would like to make a jar say jarFinal.jar contains jar1.jar, jar2.jar, jar3.jar etc. The suggestions given makes one jar extracting all class files from the dependency jars. I would like to make a jar of jars without unpacking class files.

Comment: @sridhar It sounds like One-Jar would satisfy your requirements.

Comment: There is a Maven plugin for One-Jar: http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `shade` plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for you advise but I would like to make a jar say jarFinal.jar contains jar1.jar, jar2.jar, jar3.jar etc. The suggestions given makes one jar extracting all class files from the dependency jars. I would like to make a jar of jars without unpacking class files.