# For which Maven dependency scopes is the dependency included in the compiled project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, m2e

E.g. if I make the BukkitApi jar a dependency for a maven project with depenecy scope set to provided,compile,system, runtime or test

In which scopes will the bukkitAPI be included in the compiled output?

Comment: what compiled output ? Which phase are you talking about ? e.g if you set the scope to test and nothing else, the test compiled output will obviously use the dependency. Which does not mean that it will be "included" in anything, as long as you don't explicitely include dependencies in any output (for exemple, output of the `package` phase)

Comment: I honestly don't know which phase, I'm entirely new to maven, and someone on an IRC channel confused me and I suspected they were wrong, I googled to no avail so I asked stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short version: By default, maven output (in the default `target` directory) does not include anything  except the compiled code for the current project/module. That is, nothing from dependencies.

Long(er) version: with default `jar` packaging and no custom phase configuration. here is how maven behaves on a java project:

1. the `compile` phase : the `.java` files in the `src/main/java/` directory get compiled to `.classes` files in the `target` directory. Dependencies for the `compile` scope get downloaded to your local repository.
2. the `package` phase : same as 1, plus you'll get a `jar` file in the `target` directory
3. the `install` phase : same as 2 you'll get a `jar` file in your local repository.

So, `.jar` files from dependencies are not included in anything by default !

#### So, how do I include dependencies in my "output", and what does thoses scopes mean ?

Now, using, for exemple, the `assembly` plugin to include dependencies in the output of the `package` phase (see [Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven)), you'll normally get this default behavior:

- `provided` : not included
- `compile` (default) : included
- `system` : not included
- `runtime` : included
- `test` : not included

Checkout [this link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for reference.

**EDIT:** Just try out this pom with the different scope values on `guice`, and you'll see that dependencies are included in the `fake-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` when scope is `compile` and `runtime` (this example does not need any source files)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.linagora</groupId>
    <artifactId>fake</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fake</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- system scope needs 'systemPath' attribute as well
                <systemPath>/path/to/guice/guice-3.0.jar</systemPath>
                <scope>system</scope>
            -->
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: people are claiming that compile does NOT include the dependencys in the assembled output, giving [worldguard]{https://github.com/sk89q/worldguard/blob/master/src/main/assembly/default.xml} as an example, its [pom]{https://github.com/sk89q/worldguard/blob/master/pom.xml} is it doing something non default?

Comment: You can see what the "default" is with the pom.file above. Just unzip the `fake-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` with the compile scope and see that guice files are included.

Comment: Had a look at your example. They are not using the 'jar-with-dependencies' configuration so it is, well, not "the-same-defaults-as-mine". Assembly itself is not a default in maven, it is a plugin, with custom configuration - thus, it is quite difficult to tell what is "default" and what isn't when you are already overriding the defaults ! I used `jar-with-dependencies` assembly to illustrate the effect of dependency `scope`, and here you are...

Answer (score 3):

That's not how Maven works. The dependencies just specify the classpath (for compilation, run time, testing). But the dependencies are not included in the output by default. You will have to ship all the dependency jars (at least the ones with scope compile and runtime).

Have a look at the dependency plugin. It provides goals to copy the dependencies.

To create a bundle for shipment, have a look at the assembly plugin (e.g. to create a zip file). It even provides a way to create an all-in-one jar, if that is what you're after.