# Pack dependencies of manifest-first maven project into jar

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, tycho

I want to pack the dependencies of my maven tycho eclipse-plugin project into the jar file like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven) but with an manifest-first project like the eclipse-plugin projects. I don't want to list all eclipse-plugin dependencies in the pom.xml, is there a way to let the assembly-plugin or shade-plugin work with a MANIFEST.MF file?

I want to use the eclipse-plugin in an other project and therefore the plugin should be packed into a jar with its dependencies (eclipse plug-in dependencies).

maven-assembly-plugin:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

only collects dependencies in pom file, not from manifest -> jar-with-dependencies equals normal jar except the manifest file from the jar-with-dependencies is a new simple one instead of the original manifest from the project.

mvn assembly:assembly fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli)
on project parent:
Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
```

Tycho deps:
mvn assembly:assembly has identic beginning as mvn install:

- Computing target platform
- Resolving dependencies
- Resolving class path

...for every module

Comment: When you run `mvn assembly:assembly`, do you see Tycho collecting the dependencies?

Comment: Tycho deps: When you run `mvn install`, you can see Tycho resolving dependencies. Do you get a similar output during `assembly:assembly`?

Comment: As for your error: Please post the XML config for the `maven-assembly-plugin` (everything between `<plugin>` and `</plugin>`)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the maven-dependency-plugin is what you're looking for.
I used it in the following way and it included all the manifest dependency classes into my ouptut jar.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includes>**/*.class</includes>
        <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it seems to be impossible to use [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and also [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to package dependencies computed by Tycho.

I debugged through both `maven-shade-plugin` and `maven-dependency-plugin` as `maven-dependency-plugin` successfully picks up dependencies from Tycho.

**Reason**: it seems that Tycho injects Manifest-based dependencies as SYSTEM scope dependencies (`toString()` of `project.getArtifacts()`).

```
...p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.jdt.debug:jar:jdimodel.jar:3.7.101.v20120913-153601:system, p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.jface:jar:3.8.0.v20120912-135020:system...
```

However, each Maven mojo must define its required dependency resolution via plugin descriptor property `requiresDependencyResolution`. `maven-shade-plugin` defines `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME`. This scope does not include `system` dependencies.

I temporarily modified the plugin descriptor to `test` and `maven-shade-plugin` works like a charme. However, I am not aware of any method to override a maven mojo's plugin descriptor's properties.

As `maven-assembly-plugin` defines the even smaller scope `compile`, tycho dependencies should not work for this plugin as well.

see also: [Discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Tycho-and-Maven-Dependency-Plugin-td137614.html)

Comment: The "Discussion" link doesn't work.