# How to make 3rd party dependencies of module x to arrive together with it into the classpath of module y which depends on module x?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a module in my system, we'll call it `someService`. This service depends on some infra module, we'll call it `someInfra`. The infra module depends on some 3rd party jars.

The problem is, when I build `someService`, I get `someInfra.jar` into my classpath, but I don't get its dependencies, which leads eventually to a `ClassNotFoundException` in runtime.

Upon the execution of `./gradlew clean build`, I would like to have all jars needed for a successful runtime execution.

I think maven plugin is somehow related to the issue. What should I do?

UPDATE: per Mark request I now add two `build.gradle` files, the first is of `someInfra`, the second is of `someService`

**someInfra build.gradle**

```
group="x.y
version="0.1.1-s3"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo',  name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.9')
        classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'artifactory'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'maven'

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j',                 name: 'slf4j-api',          version: '1.7.+'
    compile (group: 'org.springframework',      name: 'spring-context',     version: '4.0.3.RELEASE')
    compile (group: 'org.apache.curator',       name: 'curator-framework',  version: '2.5.+') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        exclude group: 'log4j'
    }
    compile ('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2')

    testCompile group: 'junit',                 name: 'junit',              version: '4.+'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework',   name: 'spring-test',        version: '4.0.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito',           name: 'mockito-all',        version: '1.9.+'
}

test {
    scanForTestClasses = false
}

pmd {
    toolVersion = '5.1.0'
    ignoreFailures = true
    ruleSets = []
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    ruleSetFiles = files("${rootDir}/gradle/pmd.xml")
}

findbugs {
    toolVersion = '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs")
    includeFilter = file("${rootDir}/gradle/findbugs.xml")
}
```

**someService build.gradle**

```
group="x.y"
version="0.1.4-s3"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo',  name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.9')
        classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE')

    }
}

apply plugin: 'artifactory'

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-remoting', version: '2.0.8'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version: '0.9.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: "org.hibernate", name: "hibernate-validator"
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.0'
    compile group: 'com.mangofactory' , name: 'swagger-springmvc', version: '0.8.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-remote-shell', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'x.y', name: 'someInfra', version: '0.1.1-s3'

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'

    runtime group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version:'9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    runtime group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb'
}

test {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/ApplicationTestSuite.class'
}

pmd {
    toolVersion = '5.1.0'
    ignoreFailures = true
    ruleSets = []
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    ruleSetFiles = files("${rootDir}/gradle/pmd.xml")
}

findbugs {
    toolVersion = '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs")
    includeFilter = file("${rootDir}/gradle/findbugs.xml")
}
```

Notice how `someInfra` depends on `org.apache.curator:curator-framework`.

When I execute `someService` main method (using spring-boot), I fail on

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.RetryPolicy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more
```

UPDATE: I now notice a weird behavior in which `someInfra,jar` is wrapped WITHOUT any of its dependencies, while `someService.jar` is wrapped with all its dependencies. Weird. both `build.gradle` are pretty much the same, same goes for `settings.gradle`, `gradle.properties`, `gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` (using 1.9). What the hell is going on here...

Comment: Can you perhaps link to an example of your gradle.build file? The behavior you are describing should not be happening assuming your are configuring your build correctly, which is hard to determine without an example of your build.

Comment: There you go Mark, hope you could help. 10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following after the artifactory code block

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    uploadDescriptor = true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm adding this as an answer.  Since you mentioned maven plug in, perhaps this is what you need.  You can add this into your pom.xml in the build/plugins section to get a jar with all the dependencies added.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See also this stackoverflow question:
  [Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven)

Comment: He is using Gradle, not Maven for his build tool.